# Defining a getter for document.cookie

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to define a getter for default objects like document.cookie.

```
document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function(newv) {
   console.log('accessing cookie'); 
  //what to return here??
 });
```

Returning document.cookie obviously causes a recursion. 
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you're using a browser that can successfully call `__defineGetter__`, you'd be better off using `localStorage`.

Comment: [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) non-standard, deprecated

Comment: I want to write my own logic everytime some specific properties of the DOM are being accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this -

```
var old_cookie = document.cookie;

Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
    get: function() {
        console.log('Getting cookie');
        return this._value;
    },
    set: function(val) {
        console.log('Setting cookie', arguments);
        this._value = val;
        return this._value;
    }
});

document.cookie = old_cookie;
```

When you add getters/setters to the cookie property, it wipes away the value because descriptors cannot have both accessors and a value, so you have to save the old cookie value and re-assign it after you define the accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## Chrome

```
var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document, 'cookie');

return desc.value;
```

However, I'm not sure if this will reflect updates.

## Firefox, IE 10

```
var getter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(document), 'cookie').get.bind(document)

return getter();
```

This should work perfectly.